# Set cursor order to desc but still start at beginning of table?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm having a slight bit of trouble with reversing a cursor. I have a ranking of items. If the input is 2, I want to select items 1 and 2, but have it display like this;

```
RANK
2
1
```

Right now, when I enter 2, I get

```
RANK
231
230
```

Which is the end of the table, instead of the beginning.

My the cursor is just

```
select rank, item
from itemtable
order by rank desc;
```

used in the loop like this:

```
FOR i IN REVERSE 1..v_num LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(to_char(v_RANK) || to_char(v_ITEM);            
      FETCH c_rank INTO v_rank, v_item;
        EXIT WHEN c_rank%NOTFOUND;
        END LOOP;
```

v_num being the number of items to be displayed. I've tried setting the `order by` to both `asc` and then `desc` (like `order by rank asc, rank desc`) but that didn't work. `Reverse` doesn't change anything in the output. I've looked at other questions that are similar but wasn't able to find an answer. I'm stumped. This has got to be an easy fix, I just can't seem to figure out what it is.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on when all you've given us is snippets of the code. Perhaps you could edit the question and include everything? Thanks.

Comment: Your `REVERSE` is useless because you're not actually using the value of `i` anywhere in your code. Anyway, Justin's answer is the way to get the result you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `v_num` is supposed to be the number of elements that you want returned, it sounds like you'd want to do something like

```
select *
  from (select rank, item
          from itemtable
         order by rank asc)
 where rownum <= v_num
 order by rank desc
```

If that's not what you're after, it would be helpful to post a test case (the DDL to create a table, the DML to populate that table, and the expected results) or a [link to a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eaa67/1) that we can work with.

Comment: Yep, that was right. Didn't even think to use a subquery. Thanks!